# $state.go in AngularJS is not working on sub menu

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem related to AngularJS $state.go(url). I have a list of menus, only one of them has Sub-Menus. When I log in and I click on any other menu, it properly redirects to the desired page. Even if I click on the Menu having sub-menus, the desired page is opened, but when I click on any of the sub-menu under it, the page is not redirected. Here is the menu with submenus:

[image]

However when I refresh that page, even before clicking Form 1 menu item, the submenus start to redirect on clicking.

I have put console.log before and after $state.go function and that is being called, and there is no other error showing in console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am working on AngularJS for the first time. I could not realize that I need to inject state urls to app.js. After adding it, the $state.go has started to redirect to url.